# A way to get translations of foreign papers?

Tags: translation

Is there a site which does this, or do you know of tools I could use?

Specifically I want:

FejesToth,L.1943.On covering a spherical surface with equal spherical caps. (in Hungarian).Matematikai Fiz.Lapok 50:40-46.

but can't find it anywhere in English and I certainly can't read Hungarian!

There are many though, some German, some Dutch and I was wondering if there was a general answer as well as a specific one?

Comment: Regarding the specific case you mention, I don't know exactly what's in this paper, but Fejes Tóth discusses covering problems on spheres in his book "Regular Figures" (which was translated into English); see section II.2.5.  If you read German you might also find information in "Lagerungen in der Ebene, auf der Kugel, und im Raum", but it sounds from your last sentence like you don't.  I doubt you'll find a translation of this paper, so your best bet is if he included the contents in one of these books.

Comment: Thanks, I shall check it out, I specifically want to find a proof go the upper bound he talks about with regard distances on a sphere. It is to do with Tammes's problem.

Comment: Both books say quite a bit about packing and covering on the 2-sphere.  If I remember right, there is some stuff in "Lagerungen..." that didn't make it into "Regular Figures" (for example, the optimal 7-point code in S^2), but the material dealing with regular polyhedra is in both.  So if you mean a bound in terms of trig functions that is sharp for a few regular polyhedra, I think you'll find it there.

Comment: Do you know of a way to get to the proof without the book as my uni library, council library and brothers uni library don't have it. Also its like £150 so I can't just buy it?

Comment: Did you try to ask for an interlibrary loan?

Comment: See also Theorem 4.4.1 and equation (4.19) in "Finite Packing and Covering" by K. Böröczky - are they what you are looking for?  There's a preview on http://books.google.com.